# Search for a specific string in array with O(log n) worst case in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, sorting

I am trying to understand how to find a given string in an array of string using O(log n) worst case. Any body can help me with an example?

Or what is the best practice to do so? by sorting the array? Currently is not sorted.

Comment: Yes, by sorting. Then binary search

Comment: @Renat would you be able to give me a quick example as a comment ? I want to assimilate the concept of how it should be the best to do it

Comment: @Renat Would that not make the worst case the worst case of your sort?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Sorting_and_Searching_Algorithms.html)

You can use Binary search on a sorted array to find an element in O(log n) time.

If it's not sorted, you'll have to do a linear search and look at each element of the array, which has worst case of O(n)

Answer (score 2):

> Currently is not sorted.

There is a proof that it is impossible to do better than O(nlog(n)) for any comparison sort, so as ShaneDems indicated the O(n) of linear search is your only option, *unless* assumptions about whether your list is sorted or not changes.